# Syntax highlighting for post/page editor

Tags: plugins, post-editor, syntax-highlighting, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

Anyone know of a plugin that adds syntax highlighting to the post/page HTML editor?

Thanks-

Comment: @Hans- I tried google, did you? What don't you understand about the question?

Comment: Just to clarify what you're asking(because it appears everyone is reading the question different to how i am).. You're looking for a syntax highlighter for the **post editor**, not the theme/plugin editor, would that be correct?

Answer (score 4):

I am using SyntaxHighlighter Evolved by Viper007Bond, works great!
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

After I gave this answer yesterday, I read a recent post by Konstantin Kovshenin over at theme.fm, which gives you all the different possibilities on how to add syntax into your Posts/Pages: http://theme.fm/2011/07/working-with-code-in-wordpress-posts-985/

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Power Code Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/power-code-editor/) in the past it has syntax highlighting. It's been awhile since I've used it, but it seemed to work fine then.

Answer (score 2):

I found a shortcode by **@Bainternet** in [Ohad Raz weblog](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/shotcodes-because-its-shorter) that can help you to build your sintax highlight own plugin, or just type it into your `functions.php` file theme.

```
function bainternet_highlight($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'color' => 'yellow',
    'font' => '#000000'
  ), $atts));
  return "<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: $color; color: $font\">$content</font>";
}
add_shortcode('highlight','bainternet_highlight');
```

**Usage**:  `[ highlight ] this text is highlighted [/highlight]`

Now, if you are searching for a MCE syntax highlightter, the best plugin I have found is the [Advanced code Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-code-editor/)

Hope that helped with your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking forever for the solution. I finally found this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/) which actually does a lot of things. But i only used the option to add a HTML button to the row of buttons which lets you edit post/page html with [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) highlighting.

Answer (score -1):

This one could solve the problem http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-editor-syntax-highlighter/

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104231/145551 and stop copying the same answer.

Comment: What the hell.. This is the ACTUAL answer this guy is looking for, and it gets downvoted. Meanwhile all of the other answers that were upvoted are totally unrelated to the guy's question...