# Page/post editor with syntax highlighting

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting

is there a plugin that replaces/enhances the built-in Page/Post HTML editor so that HTML is syntax-highlighted?
What I'm looking for is something like "Power Code Editor" but for editing Pages/Posts.

NOTE: Just to be absolutely clear: I am not looking for a plugin that let me post highlighted code snippets, I just want to edit the HTML code of my posts in a nicer editor :)

An added bonus would be a formatter function to cleanup the indentation.

Is anybody aware of such a plugin?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting for post/page editor](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23263/syntax-highlighting-for-post-page-editor)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking forever for the solution. I finally found this plugin which actually does a lot of things. But i only used the option to add a HTML button to the row of buttons which lets you edit post/page html with CodeMirror (http://codemirror.net/) highlighting.

Link to plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/

Answer (score 1):

I've installed the Ultimate TinyMCE plug-in. It is a bit of over-kill for syntax highlighting, but it does provide that functionality. The setting is under button group 2. It's called "HTML Code Magic Button". It does a good job of formatting and highlighting. It didn't like my `<br style="clear: both">` nor my `<p style="clear:both;"></p>`. It kept wanting to make it `<p></p>` or just clear it out totally. Other than that, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-advanced-code-editor/ - it hasn't been updated recently, but seems to work...

Comment: It works, kinda. Don't know why but it leaves the old editor grayed out but still visible in the background, which does not make editing simple. It would be great without this side-effect though

Answer (score 0):

Try this one http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-editor-syntax-highlighter/

Comment: An answer should be [more than a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please explain the Why and How. Thanks.

Comment: Works and updated to fresh WordPress. Cool. (Not works inside SiteOrigin WP Editor Widget.)