# Is there a syntax highlighting plugin for HTML View?

Tags: plugins, pages, html, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax highlighting for post/page editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23263/syntax-highlighting-for-post-page-editor)

I've googled this already to no avail, all I'm finding are syntax highlighting plugins to post actual code to the front-end of your blog (ie.. a post called "Hey check out this code snippet")

I'm talking about when you edit a POST or PAGE, is there some kind of editor that replaces just the plain textarea of HTML view.

Also note: I'm not talking about Appearance > Editor... just inside the page or post html view.

I REALLY like what Shopify.com has... its extremely nice, it would be nice to have that inside wordpress.

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking forever for the solution. I finally found this plugin which actually does a lot of things. But i only used the option to add a HTML button to the row of buttons which lets you edit post/page html with CodeMirror (http://codemirror.net/) highlighting.

Link to plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/